# BitmapFactory decodeByteArray crops Image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, crop

I'm facing a strange issue on my android app. 
i've a custom camera screen to take pictures of documents.

As you can see in pictures, Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1) saved image is same as camera screen, but in Galaxy S7 (Android 6.0.1), image is cropped from top and bottom.

S4 Camera Screen

[image: S4 Camera Screen]

S4 Result Image

[image: S4 Result Image]

S7 Camera Screen

[image: S7 Camera Screen]

S7 Result Image

[image: S7 Result Image]

My related code blocks are;
"onPictureTaken"

```
 @Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bmp = Tools.getBitmap(data);

    super.onBackPressed();        
}
```

"getBitmap"

```
public class Tools {
/*.....*/
    public static Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] data){
/*.....*/
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this happens because the cameras preview resolution is different from its output resolution.

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of tries, i've found its about output picture size as Naveen mentioned above and solved it with setPictureSize()

```
 Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(display.getHeight(), display.getWidth(), parameters);
 parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
 parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
 this.camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look to me that S4 image is same as screen, there is grey area on bottom and left.

Basically, if you crop image different than your screen ration, image won't fill whole screen. You can then either show blank space (that grey area you are showing) or center-crop it which will cut sides of your image.